# Flutter: Spaces don't display correctly before newline/line break in a multiline TextBox

Tags: flutter, dart, textbox, multiline, spaces

I have a TextField in my Flutter-app with multiline enabled

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

Whenever I have spaces at the end of a line (except the last line), they are not being displayed.
By that I mean the cursor sticks to the letters as if those spaces weren't there.

I will attach a screenshot. There are actually 5 spaces added where I painted the red line but you can't see them. If I type another letter, then you will be able to see them.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: an image]

Sorry if the image is big :) if you know how I can make it smaller please tell me, so I can do that the next time.